# flot comparison bar chart

Tags: jquery, graph, charts, flot, bar-chart

I'm trying to produce a chart in Flot that has multiple stacked bars next to each other for one data set, and a second set of stacked bars as a second data set shown underneath the main chart but off at an angle. The picture below shows what I'm after

[image: How I want it to look]

Is there any way of doing this easily? I know there is a plugin that lets me put the bars next to each other but that's not really what I'm after.

I've already got it rendering one data set how I want but I don't know how to go about doing the second data set.

Comment: One option might be to take that bar-stacking plugin and modify it for your needs.  I don't believe there are any plugins for flot that do this directly.

Comment: Yeah I've had a look through it but got pretty confused. I couldn't see how it was actually moving the bars. It suggests that it simply adding an offset but I couldn't see where it was. It also would be alright for moving the bars across but I'm not sure how I'd go about moving them up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a couple of `div`s and some css to do the stacking.  Just put one graph in each `div` and then absolutely position them within a wrapper div:

```
<div id="graph_wrap">
    Comparison Chart
    <div id="graph1"></div>
    <div id="graph2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#graph_wrap {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
}

#graph1, #graph2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
}

#graph2 {
    top: -15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/q4N4M/

Comment: I was thinking about this as an option. Looks like the easiest/fastest solution by far. A little hacky but given time constraints I'll go give this a go :)

Comment: I've got a few things to iron out RE the tickets and not having them changing the chart positions, but this solution works, cheers :)